# Split a cs file into several files; one file per class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, xsd.exe

Is there  any way to split a cs file into several files? I mean, split a cs generated by xsd tool into one file per class without use the xsd tool again.

Comment: Do you have resharper?  That will do this with a couple of mouse clicks.

Comment: Thanks men i think i will be able to do it with resharper.